# How to hande callback while using dojo for form validation

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo in my web app. On page submit, there are a few back end verifications to do. So i used

```
<struts:form id="myForm" name="myForm" theme="simple" action="Confirm" onsubmit="return verifySubmit();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I've used a publish call in the verifySubmit method. Since the dojo call happens asynchronously, the page doesnt wait for the ajax call.

dojo.event.topic.publish('/verifyVersion');

Is there a way to handle this call back?

Comment: Why are you using Dojo and then defining inline event handlers inside your HTML?

Comment: I have some client side and sever side validation to do. The verifySubmit method is for the client side ones. I want the server side validation to happen after that. Hence im calling the publish event from inside method(which will be called based on whether the client side validations are true or false). Have i understood this wrong?

Comment: I'm talking about the `onsubmit="return verifySubmit();"` part. That sets up your event handler, but it's about the absolute worst way to add an event handler to an element, not least because you're mixing in your HTML and JavaScript. Either way, seeing **more** of the code would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: onsubmit="return verifySubmit(); is so that the page will not navigate to the next page in case the validation fails. I have tried dojo.event.topic.publish('/verifyVersion'); but since the publish event does not return, the page navigates to the next. Please suggest if you know any other way to make sure the page does not navigate before validation.

Comment: I know what it's intended to do, but without seeing the code for `verifySubmit()` it's impossible to know if that's what it **is** doing. That approach (using `onsubmit="foo()"`) is also vastly outdated and shouldn't be used. Use `dojo.connect()` to add the event handler instead.